# ASP.NET Web API programmatic way of applying IQueryable to an Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

We can accept an OData query from the URL with web API and that is as simple as:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<EFType> GetBuiltInTypes()
{
    return db.EFTypes;
}
```

The data is restricted in the database as the OData query is added to the Entity Framework database query.

Let's say I want to do some work with the data before returning it:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<SomePOCO> GetBuiltInTypes()
{
    var dbQuery = from obj in FncCall() select obj;

    //Do something with the data and put the result into a 
    //List<SomePOCO>

    var list = DoSomeWork(dbQuery) //whatever

    return list.AsQueryable();
}
```

Note: `FncCall()` returns a generic `DbSet` and not a `DbSet<SomeType>`

It will still work but it will restrict the results and apply the OData query to my `list` in memory and not the `dbQuery` being applied to the database? Any simple way of doing it?

From the Microsoft documentation at:

we can do

```
public IQueryable<Product> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts) {
    var settings = new ODataValidationSettings() {
        // Initialize settings as needed.
        AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllMathFunctions
    };

    opts.Validate(settings);

    IQueryable results = opts.ApplyTo(products.AsQueryable());
    return results as IQueryable<Product>;
}
```

but I don't know the type, in this case, `Product` at compile time as what I have to work with is a `DbType`.

Comment: Well, without any context on what `DoSomeWork()` does, as long as it is something that can be translated to SQL and returned back as `IQueryable` it should be fine?

Comment: Yes but it's not a work that can be added to the query and be done in the database, it translates the object into another set type of objects.

Comment: I still fail to see why you have to use the Generic version? What method on the OData library is restricted to the Generic version of IQueryable<T>?

Comment: Maybe I'm really not seeing this correctly... I'll review it a little bit more... I'll update it later or reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do not call ToList/ToArray/AsEnumerable/etc. or anything else that would cause your IQueryable instance to call the database.

For example:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<SomePOCO> GetBuiltInTypes()
{
    var dbQuery = from obj in FncCall() select obj;
    // at this point the database has not yet been called
    IQueryable<SomePOCO> result = DoSomeWork(dbQuery);
    return result;
}

private IQueryable<SomePOCO> DoSomeWork(IQueryable<SomePOCO> dbQuery)
{
   // still not executed against db
   return dbQuery.Where(x => x.something == "something");
}
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is that I want to restrict the results and apply the query to the database before I work with it... see my last edit please :)

Comment: @PedroFigueiredo - This does exactly that. The `where` clause in the `DoSomeWork` is still applied to the end query that will be executed before the OData translated expressions are applied.